# MySQL datatype to store pair of values?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I have a table that stores a list of expected parameters that are compared against a real set of data to check if they are within range. There are a dozen or so labeled parameters, and each parameter is either an int, float, or varchar. Each parameter can have either a range like (3.5 - 6.7) or a list of possible values like ('localizer', 'local a') or (4,5,8)

This will be dynamic, so the user will be able to add to and update the list of possible values. I don't think I want to add in lots and lots rows of possible parameters unless I can't find a way to do this in the schema.

What is the best way to store these possible parameter values in a SQL table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ENUM? e.g gender ENUM('M', 'F') accepts only M or F as a value.

Comment: I've looked into that, but I basically want each column to store more than one value. This table will be user-specified, so I don't want to have to rely on a range checking in the schema. The table isn't meant to validate numbers going into the database, it's meant to help validate existing data elsewhere in the system.

Comment: I think this isn't about SQL nor mySQL but about your application. I think you should implement those specification into your application to allow users to enter what you mentioned above.